High CPU Usage by php-cgi in WordPress Admin Panel
I’m running a WordPress site on a server with AlmaLinux 9 and cPanel. The site itself is fast, but the admin panel is very slow.
When I check the server using htop, I see php-cgi processes consuming 94%-96% of CPU when accessing the admin panel. I have 34 active WordPress plugins, many of which are essential and cannot be disabled.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Adjusted php.ini settings (increased memory_limit, max_execution_time).
Optimized the database.
Disabled unnecessary dashboard widgets.

Despite these changes, the admin panel remains slow with high CPU usage. Any suggestions for further optimization?
Server Details:

OS: AlmaLinux 9
cPanel installed
PHP version: 8.1
WordPress version: latest version
Active plugins: 34


I'm also facing exact same issue, I also have same server config. Already spent a lot of time, can't figure it out. There is a discussion thread on https://techoforum.com/t/woocommerce-slow/410/1 keep an eye on that, may be someone can come up with a solution.
